# Date Filter incorrectly formatting the date value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a variable `dateSubmitted` having the value `dateSubmitted": "07-09-20:11:03:30`

I am using `Angular Version 7`

I am using the date filter within HTML to format the date as below:

```
<td> {{element.dateSubmitted | date:'MMMM d, y'}} </td>
```

The date value is correct but the year is incorrectly showing as `2001` in the output `July 9, 2001`

The correct output is `July 9, 2020`

Comment: The date filter is fine, your date string is incorrect really. A year should always be a full year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DatePipe input value](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#input-value)
value – The date expression:

- a Date object
- a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch)
- an ISO string (https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Your date does not conform to ISO string specification, in particular, it has year at the end. The parser seems to interpret is as an hour.

Compare:

```
new Date('07-09:11:03:30')
// Sun Jul 01 2001 09:11:03 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
new Date('07-09-:11:03:30')
// Mon Jul 09 2001 11:03:30 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
new Date('07-09-20:11:03:30')
// Mon Jul 09 2001 20:11:03 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```